# How to upload image using javascript, ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to upload an image in `onchange` of the input type file using **AJAX**. I can only use **javascript, ajax and php.**

Look my code:

**index.html**

```
<form id="myForm" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="imagefile" id="imagefile" onchange="uploadImage()">
</form>
```

**upoad.js**

```
function uploadImage(){

    try {
       ajpass = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
       ajpass = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
       ajpass.onreadystatechange = epasscheck2;
       ajpass.open("post", "http://localhost/moodle/lib/editor/tinymce/plugins/moodleimage/upload.php", true);

       ajpass.send();
}
function epasscheck2() {
   if ((ajpass.readyState == 4) && (ajpass.status == 200)) {
       var restxt = ajpass.responseText;  
       alert(restxt);
    }
}
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php

  echo $_FILES["imagefile"]["name"]; //error here

  //file upload code here

?>
```

I am getting the error `Undefined index imagefile` in `upload.php`.

I am failed to pass the image file properties(like name, size, tmp_name etc) from `upload.js` to `upload.php`.

Comment: Try single dimensional array i.e $_FILES["imagefile"]

Comment: Already tons of posts are there on SO , still don't know?

Answer (score 0):

use the coding below it will help you to validate file

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
 $("#form").on('submit',(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
         url: "upload.php",
   type: "POST",
   data:  new FormData(this),
   contentType: false,
         cache: false,
   processData:false,
   beforeSend : function()
   {
    //$("#preview").fadeOut();
    $("#err").fadeOut();
   },
   success: function(data)
      {
    if(data=='invalid file')
    {
     // invalid file format.
     $("#err").html("Invalid File !").fadeIn();
    }
    else
    {
     // view uploaded file.
     $("#preview").html(data).fadeIn();
     $("#form")[0].reset(); 
    }
      },
     error: function(e) 
      {
    $("#err").html(e).fadeIn();
      }          
    });
 }));
});
```

```html
<form id="form" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" />
  <input id="button" type="submit" value="Upload">
 </form>
<div id="err"></div>
```

you must create a folder "upload".

```
   <?php

$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'); // valid extensions
$path = 'uploads/'; // upload directory

if(isset($_FILES['image']))
{
 $img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
 $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

 // get uploaded file's extension
 $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

 // can upload same image using rand function
 $final_image = rand(1000,1000000).$img;

 // check's valid format
 if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions)) 
 {     
  $path = $path.strtolower($final_image); 

  if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path)) 
  {
   echo "uploaded";
  }
 } 
 else 
 {
  echo 'invalid file';
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: I am asking for javascript not jquery

Comment: @next2u https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/uploading-files-with-ajax--net-21077 please checkout this link.

Comment: thankyou Jasjeet Singh, for the link..And this link also helpful http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax

Answer (score -1):

I feel like a necromancer right now, but regardless, it seems to me that the primary issue in this case was that no actual data was sent in the send() function. Since XMLHttpRequest is being used the form data isn't sent with it as it would be through a redirect directly through HTML. To rectify this, we'd need to first of all grab the file.

```
const img = document.getElementById("imagefile");
if (img.files.length == 0) return;
const file = img.files[0];
```

After which I suppose all there is left to do is to actually send the data.

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append("imagefile", file);
ajpass.send(data);
```

And with this, you hopefully would get a working result. Since I'm feeling generous, I'll also give you an extra PHP bit that can be useful.

```
if (isset($_FILES['imagefile']) {
...
}
```

isset() will more easily help you see if what you're looking for actually exists within the context. It makes finding where things go wrong if they do, and you can avoid nasty error messages.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Dropzone instead of reinventing the wheel,

Here's the link : http://www.dropzonejs.com/#